# Squeaky door hinge cannot be solved

Tags: door, squeaking

I have already read [this post](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/3538/squeaky-door-gets-the-grease) and it's not helping me. I have a 2015 RAM 1500 and both driver-side doors squeak badly when opening/closing. I have already tried the following:

1. Sewing machine oil (easy and gentle, little mess)
2. White lithium grease from a spray can
3. Heavy black grease from a tube.

In all cases, the squeak goes away for about 2 days, then it comes right back with a vengeance. Part of me says I must not be hitting the actual squeaky parts, else the heavy grease would certainly end the squeak for months at least. But the other part of me says, if I'm not hitting the squeaky part, why would the squeak go away for about 2 days, no matter what lubricant I use?

Here is a photo of my hinge. You can see the gobs of grease all over it, and I tried to get it into every little angle and crevice.

What else can I try?

[image: Door hinge]

Comment: is the spring slipping when you move the door? or is it the actual hinge?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but the spring is lubed up also.

Comment: If you remove the spring does it still make noise?

Comment: Hmmm...I don't see how I could remove that. Shoot, I have no mechanical ability.

Comment: If you support the door and unbolt the hinge you can remove the spring. It's worth a shot to see if the spring is sliding on the seat making the noise. Try cleaning off some of the grease and look for wear spots or if you can use a stethoscope to isolate where it's squeaking.

Answer (score -1):

Clean off the grease well and try silicone spray